# Tyepscript : .toString(16) - Error Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: typescript, hex

I am trying to convert a number into hexadecimal using the number.toString(16) function but it is giving me the error `Error Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`.

I might be doing something wrong with my types, because I believe it should work.

Here is my code :

```
type ImageToEncode = {
  pixelsAndColors: string[][][];
  bounds: string[][][];
  paletteIndex: string;
}

task("encodeImage", "Encode an image", async function(taskArgs: ImageToEncode) {
  
  const hexPixelsAndColors = taskArgs.pixelsAndColors
  .map((array: string[][]) => {
      let firstChar = array[0].toString(16);
      let secondChar = array[1].toString(16);
      if(firstChar.length < 2) {
          firstChar = `0${firstChar}`;
      }
      if(secondChar.length < 2) {
          secondChar =`0${secondChar}`;
      }
      return [firstChar, secondChar];
  })
  .map((array: string[]) => array.join(""))
  .join("");

  const hexBounds = taskArgs.bounds.map(bound => {
    let firstChar = bound.toString(16);
    if(firstChar.length < 2) {
        firstChar = `0${firstChar}`;
    }
    return firstChar;
}).join("");

  const hexData = `0x${taskArgs.paletteIndex}${hexBounds}${hexPixelsAndColors}`
  console.log(hexData);
  return hexData;
});
```

For information can be interpreted like a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toString` expects an argument for `number.toString` whereas you are trying to call `toString` with array of strings, or even `string[][]`. It is not correct `let firstChar = array[0].toString(16) // expected error`.

If you want to convert `string` to `hexadecimal` you should use `parseInt(string, 10).toString(16)`.

For example: `parseInt("100", 10).toString(16) // 64`

If you have an array of strings, you can parse the whole array with help of this function:

```js
const toHex = (str: string) => parseInt(str, 10).toString(16)

const result = ['10', '42'].map(toHex)
```